# MySql: Insert multiple rows with the same unique indentifier

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table for team partners:

```
id - Primary Key (auto inc)
first_name - text
last_name - text
team_number - number
```

I insert two records at the same time, and I want them to have a unique (if possible auto incrementing) team number.

At the moment, I do a count of the current table results, add 1 and insert that as a team number.

If I had 20 people entering data at the same time, I believe there's a risk of two teams getting the same team number.

Are my fears based in reality? If so, how do I mitigate that?

Comment: team number can be common? two or more person  can belong to one team. Isn't it. If not in your case then before inserting check and then isert/reject

Comment: It's a plain number field, so it's not really auto increment.

Comment: I'd want to insert two people (at the same time) and they would share this number. I wouldn't want anyone else to have that number though.

Comment: You should let the auto increment primary key handle uniqueness here.  Just do the inserts and don't worry about it.

Comment: @Richard In that case you should be making that check in application logic imo. You can't have something unique that's not unique.

Comment: As i said check before insert that the same team_number have how many people ? if >=2 then rejct the new insert and ask to add another team_number. (>=2 means one tem can have 1 or 2 members only)

Comment: I know the ideal would be to insert an array of player ids into a row with an auto-incrementing id, but the application isn't built that way.

If there's no "rock solid" approach, I'll have to rewrite a chunk of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you do not mean that 'team_number' should be really unique, right?

So a team is based on two players, right?
If so I would suggest to handle the logic in the program itself.
Why you didn`t create a queue for that?

In that case you can insert 100 members at once but the queue should only get two at the same time and insert them before getting the next two members!?

Or do you need to handle this problem via SQL?

Comment: I think a queue would work just fine. 
Thanks for the advice!